# phonegap angularjs barcodescanner

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have this solution in visual studio where I am creating a cordova project. I have also installed ngCordova and the phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner plugin.

I have injected ngCordova and made this function:

```
$scope.scan = function() {

   $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  },
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  });

};
```

but it fails on:
cordova.plugins is undefined

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 1):

**Cordova plugins run only on real devices or emulators.**

The `scan()` method return a promise:

```
$cordovaBarcodeScanner
  .scan()
  .then(function(barcodeData) {
    // Success! Barcode data is here
    console.log(barcodeData);
  }, function(error) {
    // An error occurred
    console.log(error);
  });
```

If you want testing your app running in the browser you could use a mock like this:

```
if (!window.cordova){
  window.cordova = {
    plugins: {
      barcodeScanner: {
        scan: function (success, error) {
          var code = window.prompt("Enter barcode value (empty value will fire the error handler):");
          if(code) {
            var result = {
              text:code,
              format:"Fake",
              cancelled:false
            };
            success(result);
          } else {
            error("No barcode");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```